# What exactly happens when you press the "play" button in Unity?

Tags: process, background, unity-game-engine

As soon as you hit "Play" what happens in the background of the software? The code is already compiled and ready at this point. So when I press "Play" the code gets executed. What other things occur along with this?

I have this question as an assignment and would really like to know. Thanks. :)

Comment: Interesting, googled and could not find a single source about it. Could be related to magic and shamanism probably. Almost definitely unity is generating a new build after change of even a single character in a script. Same as Android Studio or many other IDE's do by default. Only thing I can help you with is if you hit pause button and THEN play button Unity will execute all the Awake() and, if possible, OnEnable() + Start() functions. Then it will execute the Update() once. It will pause only after that. Well, not much of an info I know, please post an answer if you find a good one.

Comment: I believe nothing at all is "built" when you just press Play.  It is a totally and completely different pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually everything is loaded by script. [This](http://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/monobehaviour_flowchart.svg) graph explains the process. Also the links below can be useful for you to understand all the background process.

[Execution Order of Event Functions](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

[Overview: Script compilation](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html)

Comment: That is actually what I've been looking for! How did you find it? I spent a day googling about this!!

Comment: Surprisingly this answer, I'm afraid, actually has no connection at all to the question.  The two links given here are entirely about *what happens in the runloop* of Unity.  It's completely mysterious how the "in editor 'Play' simulator" works in comparison to actual builds.  (I have utterly no clue: I don't even know, for example!, if the scripts are interpreted [how?] or compiled in the 'Editor-Play' magic: since it's instant compared to making a build, perhaps the former?)